# How to set width and height / position ui when show up in maya?

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya, pyside2

I made a tool script for Maya.
It works. I just want to set default position/at least ui size when it show up.

Is there anyway to do this?

I already tried with some 7 commands. None of 'em works.
Most of the code tested in vscode with python 2.7 (Anaconda2)

Images:

What I tried:

[image]

How it looks and what I want:

[image]

```
# class and define prCLSRU tool
class pr_clsru_toolUI(pr_clsru_toolUI_form, pr_clsru_toolUI_base):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    # def __init__(self, parent=None, width=370, height=318): <-------- 1st try, nothing happen. When window show up, the size of window quite large
        super(pr_clsru_toolUI, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setDockNestingEnabled(True)
        #self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(370, 318)) <-------- 2nd try, nothing happen
```

```
if cmds.window( window_name, exists=True ):
    cmds.deleteUI( window_name )
else:
    cmds.window( title="prCLSRU tool for Maya v1.0.0", iconName="prCLSRU tool for Maya", widthHeight=(370, 318) ) #<-------- 3rd try, nothing happen. When window show up, the size of window quite large

if cmds.window( window_name, exists=True ):
    cmds.deleteUI( dock_control )
else:
    cmds.window( title="prCLSRU tool for Maya v1.0.0", iconName="prCLSRU tool for Maya", widthHeight=(370, 318) ) #<-------- 4th try, nothing happen. When window show up, the size of window quite large
```

```
window = pr_clsru_toolUI( MayaWindowPtr )
#7th try to resize
#cmds.window( window_name, edit=True, widthHeight=(370, 318) ) <-------- 7th try, nothing happen. When window show up, the size of window quite large
window.setObjectName( window_name )
# cmds.window( widthHeight=(370, 318) ) <-------- 5th try, nothing happen. When window show up, the size of window quite large
# cmds.window(resize(370, 318)) <-------- 6th try, nothing happen. When window show up, the size of window quite large
main = QDockWidget( dock_control, MayaWindowPtr )
main.setAllowedAreas( Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea|Qt.RightDockWidgetArea )
main.setObjectName( dock_control )
main.setWidget( window )
main.setFloating( True )
main.show()
```

As you can see. What I want is set the height and width when I click the button on shelf. (inside dark teal box)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as Dhruv suggested.
To make it pop out in the middle and has correct size.
used:
main.resize("widthValue", "heightValue")

just put it befor: 
 main.set*etc.etc.*

Thank you, @DhruvGovil

*sample below*
https://twitter.com/prsfx/status/1168040492556115970/photo/1

Comment: you could use setGeometry too.